# How do you create your own multidimensional array?

Tags: ruby

I am coding and I came across this problem in my code, How do you create your own multidimensional array in Ruby? I tried searching up but none of the websites could help.

Comment: Are you talking about something like a 2 or 3 dimensional matrix?

Answer (score 1):

There are no multidimentional arrays in Ruby (at least they are not first class citizens.)

One might simulate this behavior by creating an array containing arrays of the same length:

```
arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

or, dynamically:

```
arr = Array.new(2) { |_| Array.new(2) }
```

Also, there is [`Matrix`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class in standard library.

Comment: "There are no multidimentional arrays in Ruby" – I guess that's the reason why the OP asks about creating them?